# Spring Integration Channel naming convention

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

My question is simple, is there any known convention for naming channels in Spring Integration (or more generally in Enterprise Integration Patterns)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the informal convention is to use a `channel` as a suffix, but there is indeed no any requirements.

In case of Spring this channel name really becomes a *bean name*, so you could filter beans by some common suffix/prefix. However at the same time all the channel beans are instances of the `MessageChannel`... At the same time no one stops you to use the same prefix/suffix in other places...

We also have a convention to name channels for `input` with an `input` key word. Same for `output`. Or request/reply...

So, everything is flexible and is not tied to some strong naming requirements.